# Mouse cursor flickering when streaming video in Chrome. Browser window gets grayed out

Tags: ubuntu, video, streaming, mouse

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Asus laptop. I am not attaching any secondary monitor to it.

Since few weeks I noticed that when I am watching Youtube videos sometimes the mouse cursor starts flickering: it seems it's quickly switching between the arrow and the hand cursor. After few seconds the Chrome window gets grayed out.

Please note the video is NOT flickering, just the mouse cursor.

I noticed also that the laptop is less responsive in in general so I am assuming Chrome is probably using more CPU and RAM.

The only temporary solution I found is to double click on the window top bar so it becomes smaller.

So far I tried

- sudo apt get upgrade
- restart chrome
- check the Display in system settings: it does not show any "unknown
  monitor"
- deleting browsing data files in chrome

Thanks!